# Se pasma barra de progreso del ProgressBar en C# windows form

Tags: c#, windows-forms, backgroundworker

Realice el cambio que me mencionaron lo utilice de la siguiente manera pero cuando entra el proceso se pasma y avanza hasta que termina el proceso , igual pongo en la parte de mi timer que es donde inicia este lo siguiente: para que me aparezca la barra verde igual no se que pongo mal igual para que se vea el movimiento agrego una ventana BarraProgreso.PerformStep();. Entendi que debe de iniciarse el proceso con este bg.RunWorkerAsync(); pero igual no lo marca solo me aparece la ventana al final.

Espero me puedan apoyar, gracias.

```
private void Inicializar_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtMensaje.Text = "";
            BarraProgreso.Value = 25;
            txtProceso.Text = "Procesando...";
            lblTiempo.Visible = true;
            BarraProgreso.Visible = true;
            
            bg.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            bg.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            bg.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;
            bg.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork;
            bg.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;

            timerProceso.Start();
        }


private void barraProgreso_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timerProceso.Start();
        }
```

//Aquí se encuentra la actualizacion arriba mencionada

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
            {
     
    
           int progress = 0;
            while (progress < 100)
            {
                progress++;
                bg.ReportProgress(progress);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
    
    
        }

Este es mi proceso entra aqui y se congela la barra.



 private void timerProceso_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                timerProceso.Enabled = false;
                DialogResult dresulConfirmacion = MessageBox.Show("Seguro que desea iniciar?", "Mensaje", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                if (dresulConfirmacion == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    DateTime ldatFechaActual = DateTime.Now;
    
                    try
                    {
                        BarraProgreso.Maximum = 100;
                        BarraProgreso.Step = 25;
                        bg.RunWorkerAsync();
                        string lstrFechaInicio = dateFechaInicio.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
                        string lstrFechaActual = ldatFechaActual.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
    
                        if (lstrFechaInicio != lstrFechaActual)
                        {
                            BarraProgreso.PerformStep();
    
                            DateTime ldatFechaInicio = dateFechaInicio.Value;
                            DateTime ldatFechaFin = ldatFechaInicio.AddDays(5);
                            dateFechaFin.Value = ldatFechaFin;
    
                            if (dateFechaInicio.Value.Date > ldatFechaActual || lstrFechaInicio == lstrFechaActual)
                            {
    }
    }else
    {}
```

Comment: Yo leí tu pregunta anterior, y lo que pasa es que la respuesta es genérica, no es la solución especifica a tu problema. El `While` que has puesto en el `backgroundWorker1_DoWork` puede NO tener sentido en tu caso (lo más probable). En esa función tu debes colocar lo que TU estas procesando

Comment: justo anteriormente lo tenia solo el nombre de mi proceso , osea el timer donde esta todo pero igual no me realiza nada

Comment: Es que ese timer sobra absolutamente. Que es lo que quieres procesar??

Comment: es un proceso que va a estar ejecutandose tipo rpa

Comment: Pero ponle más ganas a la explicación, hagamos cuenta que tu estas más interesado que yo en resolver el problema